# How do I implement sequelize migration down functionality for databases?

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, database-migration, sequelize.js

In Sequelize.js, i have created an example migration file:

```
module.exports = {
  up: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    // add altering commands here, calling 'done' when finished
    migration.createTable('Users', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER, 
            primaryKey: true, 
            autoIncrement: true, 
        }, 
        createdAt: {
          type: DataTypes.DATE
        },
        updatedAt: {
          type: DataTypes.DATE
        },
        firstname: DataTypes.STRING, 
        lastname: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING, 
        password: DataTypes.STRING,
    });
    done()
  },
  down: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    // add reverting commands here, calling 'done' when finished
    done()
  }
}
```

Could someone explain the use cases and possible implementation of both up and down functionality?

Thank you!

Comment: If you not see cases in your project, don't use this function.
Keep it short and simple.
For example: create dbsync script and run it when you update the model.

Comment: Hi, 
I am unaware of possible use cases. Sequelize Documentation does not explain this thoroughly. Could you show me an example?
Thank you!

Comment: What's your question exactly? I don't understand it quite well.... If you mean what's up and what's down:
- up: all commands will be executed when running sequelize db:migrate
- down: all commands will be executed when running sequelize db:migrate:undo.

Sequelize also says the development environment is default, but I experienced problems with this. So I have to execute all commands with --env development at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got to see the thing like if your database have 2 different "states", before migration and after migration.

Before you start any migration you don't have any `Users` table, so lets say that your database is in "state 1".

When you run the up migrations ( `sequelize db:migrate` ) you pass your database to "state 2" ( now you have the `Users` table in your database ).

If anything went wrong or you changed your mind about this migration, you can go back to "state 1" again by running the down functionality ( `sequelize db:migrate:undo` ) doing the opposite of the up functionality.

In this case its simple, if you are creating a `Users`, to reverse you have only to delete it and you go back to "state 1" again.

```
module.exports = {

    up: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {

        // add altering commands here, calling 'done' when finished
        migration.createTable( 'Users', {

            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
            },
            createdAt: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE
            },
            updatedAt: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE
            },
            firstname: DataTypes.STRING,
            lastname: DataTypes.STRING,
            email: DataTypes.STRING,
            password: DataTypes.STRING,

        })
        .nodeify( done );
    },

    down: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    // add reverting commands here, calling 'done' when finished

        migration.dropTable('Users')
        .nodeify( done );

    }

};
```

Per example, if you were going to delete the `Users` table instead of creating it, you just have to exchange the up and down code.